# SharePoint 2013 modal dialog close callback

Tags: popup, modal-dialog, sharepoint-online

I have made a modal dialog that shows on page load. It shows an aspx page. Heres the code:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, 'sp.ui.dialog.js');

function initialize() {

var options = {
title: "Välkommen",
width: 600,
height: 400,
url: "https://contosoab703.sharepoint.com/pages/welcomepage.aspx"
dialogReturnValueCallback: onCloseCallback
};

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)

}
```

I want to have a option for the user that says: "do not show this popup in the future.."

Is it possible to have a callback and it checks if user have pushed that button. If it has then hide the popup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
- On the dialog ready, create cookie so save state. 
- Before show dialog, check the cookie

Answer (score -1):

You could create a separate list to log the users who have clicked that button. In the callback function, use SPServices to update that list.

Also have an SPServices function to check that list prior to calling the dialog.

Note: SPServices requires jQuery

SPServices: http://spservices.codeplex.com

jQuery: http://jquery.com/